# Monotonic function; limits from the right and from the left

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, epsilon-delta

Can someone explain this to me? It seems quite easy, but somehow I can't manage to prove this on my own ... or in other words: when exactly does a function $f$ ***not*** have  limits from the right and from the left ? (Picture is a screenshot from wikipedia)
[image]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Without loss of generality, assume $f$ is monotonic increasing. At any given point $a$, $f(x) \le f(a)$ for $x<a$. The least upper bound of the $f(x)$ for $x<a$ is the left-handed limit of $f(x)$ at $a$.

For the right-handed limit, use the greatest lower bound of $f(x)$ for $a<x$.

The jump from LUB and GLB to limit is not trivial but is pretty easy to show.

**ADDED:**

There are [four kinds of discontinuity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classification_of_discontinuities) (for real functions of one real variable). **Removable discontinuities** (the one-sided limits exist and are equal but do not equal $f(a)$) and **jump discontinuities** (the one-sided limits exist but are not equal) have one-sided limits. **Infinite discontinuities** (one or both of the one-sided limits is $+\infty$ or $-\infty$) have one-sided limits or not, depending if you consider an infinite limit to be a limit. (The textbook I teach from does not.)

An **oscillating discontinuity** lacks one or both one-sided limits. A common example of this is $\sin(\frac 1x)$ at $x=0$. Another example is
$$f(x) =
\begin{cases}
1,  & \text{if $x$ is rational} \\
-1, & \text{if $x$ is irrational}
\end{cases}
$$

Both of these examples vary from $-1$ to $1$ in any open interval bounded by zero. In fact, the second one has an oscillating discontinuity at any real value.

Note that a function monotonic in an interval is either continuous or has a jump discontinuity at any point in the interval.

**ADDED LATER:**

Here is a proof that (for a monotonic increasing function $f(x)$ defined for all real numbers) that the least upper bound of $f(x)$ for $x<a$ is $\lim_{x \to a^-}{f(x)}$.

Suppose we are given that $f(x)$ is monotonic increasing on $\mathbb R$ and we are given $a \in \mathbb R$ and $\epsilon>0$. Since $f(a)$ is an upper bound of $f(x)$ for $x<a$ there must be a least upper bound: let's call it L.

Consider $L-\epsilon$. By the definition of LUB it cannot be an upper bound for $f(x)$, so there is a value $b<a$ where $f(b)>L-\epsilon$. Since L is an upper bound, $f(b) \le L$. Let $\delta=a-b$, which is positive.

Then, for any $x$ such that $a-\delta<x<a$,
$$L-\epsilon \le f(x) \le L$$
Since we found a positive $\delta$ for any $\epsilon>0$, that is almost the very definition of

$$\lim_{x \to a^-}{f(x)}=L=LUB_{x<a}(f(x))$$

Comment: is this the whole proof? could you explain to me when a function does not have a left(/right)-handed limit ?

Comment: @Christian: As I said, you still need to show that the least upper bound of $f(x)$ for $x<a$ is the left-hand limit of $f(x)$ as $x$ approaches $a$. That is not hard: let us know if you need help there.

Comment: Okay, I think I got it now - thank you so far. The only problem I have is to show it mathematically properly. 
Is the following okay? 
We assume that an upper bound exist, which is less than $f(a)$. Let $\varepsilon \gt 0 $.
Then there must exist
$$\lim \limits_{x \to a} f(x) \lt f(a) - \varepsilon $$

$$ f(a) \lt f(a) - \varepsilon$$

$$e \lt 0$$  which is a contradiction.

Comment: @Christian: No, that is not okay. You seem to assume that the least upper bound of $f(x)$ for $x<a$ is $f(a)$, but that is not the case. For example, consider the signum function $sgn(x)=-1$ for $x<0$, $0$ for $x=0$, and $1$ for $x>0$. The left-hand limit and LUB at $a=0$ is $-1$, the right-hand limit and GLB is $1$, and neither of them equals $f(0)=0$.

Comment: So, is at least my approach correct? How would you do it?

Comment: @Christian: See my "Added Later" in my answer.

Comment: Could you explain the last coloumn to me? 
" Since we found a positive δ for any ϵ>0, " 
Sorry that I may be annoying, but I really want to understand it; otherwise your previous work would be for nothing...

Comment: Do you understand the formal definition of a left-hand limit? For any $\epsilon>0$ there exists a $\delta>0$ such that for all $x$, $a-\delta<x<a \implies |f(x)-L|<\epsilon$

Comment: I understand what is meant with it, but I do not understand why exactly THIS is the definition of a left-hand limit.

Comment: I made a slight mistake and have corrected it. My line "$L-\epsilon \le f(x) \le L$" implies "$|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$ which is the definition of left-handed limit.

Comment: I am more familiar with the "oscillating discontinuity". Seems like, in that case, the limit does not exist. I think both your oscillating discontinuity and your infinite discontinuity belongs to the class of "essential discontinuity"?

Comment: @dodo: According to the Wikipedia article I link to in my answer, namely [four kinds of discontinuity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classification_of_discontinuities), as of today, you are basically correct. My oscillating discontinuity is the same as essential continuity, and an infinite discontinuity is a special case of oscillating / essential discontinuity. I wouldn't worry too much over the terminology, which differs from source to source, as long as you understand the concepts.