# Something formally similar to zero point theorem but (in fact?) different

Tags: real-analysis, monotone-functions

Assume $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are two real-valued functions defined on $[0,1]$, $f(0) > 0$ and $f(1) < 0$. $g(x)$ is continuous on $[0,1]$ and $f(x) + g(x)$ is STRICTLY increasing on $[0,1]$. Prove that there exists $\xi \in [0,1]$ s.t. $f(\xi) = 0$.

I tried to use imitate the proof of zero point theorem, but I cannot find a way to use the increasing of $f(x) + g(x)$. Any ideas about the problem?

Comment: i think this calls for the middle value theorem, but the increasing of $f(x)+g(x)$ may be used to derive continuity of $f(x)$ and then use middle-value theorem

Comment: What do you know about increasing functions?

Comment: $f(x)$ is not necessarily continuous. e.g. $f(x) = -2x+2(0 \le x \le \frac{1}{2})$ or $f(x) = -4x+3(\frac{1}{2} < x \le 1)$

Comment: Nothing. We just know $f(x) + g(x)$ is increasing...

Comment: Anything about the limit of an increasing function?

Comment: I think the preposition is true for any increasing function, and there is no additional restriction on the limit of the increasing function, i.e. It may or may not exist. I think this it the trickiest part.

Comment: see this https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Limit_of_Monotone_Real_Function/Increasing

Comment: Your $f$ cannot be increasing since $f(1) >f(0)$.

Comment: The property linked by Nikos is key to your question. Do you know that?

Comment: This is the same as finding a value where $f(x)+g(x)=g(x)$.  $f(0)+g(0)>g(0)$,  $f(1)+g(1)<g(1)$.  Should be able to go from there, $g$ continuous, and $f+g$ increasing

Comment: or more precisely, [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1044938/monotonic-function-limits-from-the-right-and-from-the-left)

Comment: I'm still kinda confused. Do we need to use zero point theorem any more?

Comment: By the zero point theorem do you mean [this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem#:~:text=In%20mathematical%20analysis%2C%20the%20intermediate,some%20point%20within%20the%20interval.)

Comment: Yeah, I was talking about that one.

Comment: BTW, please avoid "[no clue question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933)". Try to add some background to it..

Comment: Thank you so much. I'll try to avoid it later!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.** Being monotone, $f+g$ has left (resp. right) limits at each $x\in(0,1]$ (resp. $x\in[0,1)$, hence so does $f$ because $g$ is continuous.

**2.** $f$ may have jumps discontinuities, that is there may be some points $x\in(0,1)$ with $f(x+)\not=f(x-)$. But because $f+g$ is strictly increasing and $g$ is continuous,  any such jump satisfies $f(x+)-f(x-)>0$.

**3.** To get from $f(0)>0$ to  $f(1)<0$, the graph of $f$ must cross the $x$-axis. By **2.**, the graph can't jump across. A continuous crossing implies a zero! Consider, for example, $\xi:=\sup\{x\in(0,1]: f(x)>0\}$.