# Approximation of jump times of cadlag adapted processes by stopping times running over rationals

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, analysis, measure-theory, stochastic-calculus

I need some help proving the details of the proof of Lemma 6 from the following link also attached below: https://almostsuremath.com/2009/11/15/stopping-times-and-the-debut-theorem/

These facts seem straightforward however, I am having difficulty actually writing them down. I would greatly appreciate some help here.

So assuming that $X$ is a cadlag adapted process, we would like to approximate the graph $$\{(t,\omega) \in \mathbb{R}_+ \times \Omega: \Delta X_t(\omega) \neq 0\}$$ by the union of the graphs $[\tau_{s,\epsilon}]$, where we define for positive rationals $s,\epsilon$ $$\tau_{s,\epsilon} = \inf \{t \ge s: |\Delta X_t| > \epsilon\}.$$

My first question is, why is the union of the graphs $[\tau_{s,\epsilon}]$ over positive rationals $s,\epsilon$ equal to the set of time at which $\Delta X \neq 0$? The case for rational $\epsilon$'s is clear, but I am not sure how considering only the infimum over the times $\ge$ rational points is enough here. This seems obvious but I can't write down the argument for it.

Finally, when we define $$U_n = \sup \{|X_v - X_u|: u,v \in T, |v-u|<1/n\}$$ for a countable dense subset $T$ of $[s,t]$ including $t$, how does the cadlag property of $X$ guarantee that we have $$\sup_{u \in (s,t]}|\Delta X_u| = \lim_{n\to \infty} U_n?$$ Again I am not sure how the cadlag property passes over to the jumps of $X$ to give this equivalence. Also, it feels like we need the right continuity of the filtration for this to work but the post explicitly states only the completion assumption on the filtration.

These are some arguments that seem trivial when reading but has been very difficult for me to write down. I would greatly appreciate if anyone could clarify these points to me.

[image]

Comment: Regarding your first question, can you show that if $(t,\omega)$ belongs to one set, then it belongs to the other one?

Comment: @d.k.o. If for some rational $s, \epsilon>0$, $\tau_{s,\epsilon}(\omega) = t$, then I can see that we must have $|\Delta X_t|>0$ from right continuity. On the other hand, if $|\Delta X_t(\omega)|>0$, then we must have $|X_t - X_{t-}|>\delta$ for some $\delta>0$, so for any rational $s<t$ close enough, we have $|X_t -X_s|>\delta$. But I can't show why for some rational $s$, we have the first $t\ge s$ $\tau_{s,\epsilon}(\omega)=t$, that is the first jump occuring after $s$ is at $t$.

Comment: $X$ is cadlag, i.e., left limits exist. This implies that there exists a rational $s$ s.t. $|X_{t-}-X_s|<|\Delta X_t|/2$, for example.

Comment: @d.k.o. yes but how does that prove that $\tau_{s,\epsilon} (\omega) = t$ for some $s,\epsilon$ rational? What you have written means that the left limit of $X$ at $t$ can be approximated within the jump of $X$ at $t$ by any rational $s$ smaller than $t$.

Comment: @nomadicmathematician For a cadlag process, it can only have finitely many jumps that have magnitude larger than some threshold $\delta$ on any compact interval $[0,t]$.